# Apache HTTP Fallback if SSL Handshake fails

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, apache-2.4, apache2

I have a *very* specific use case. I want to check, using an Apache, if a user's browser is capable of using modern CipherSuites.

The Apache ist called with https and should try to establish a SSL connection, if that fails the Apache should redirect the user to a fallback HTTP site, where he is told that his browser is outdated.

Sure thing I need to use mod_rewrite, which even has a https variable which contains on/off, depending if SSL is established. But how can I tell apache to continue if the initial SSL Handshake fails?

Comment: just read @HBruijn answer. But what you refer "redirect" can only happen once ssl is stablished, and there is not such thing in SSL as redirect even less if the handshake has not been stablished.

Answer (score 1):

> the client should try to establish a SSL connection, if that fails the Apache should redirect the user to a fallback HTTP site, where he is told that his browser is outdated.

I think you can't, the TLS handshake would fail at a stage well before the stage where the client and webserver can exchange HTTP protocol messages.

Instead:

1. Accept all ciphers.
2. And order them from strong to weak with the [`SSLCipherSuite ...`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) directive.
3. Don't allow the client to determine the preference of cipher, but negotiate them in the order of preference you determined in step 2. with the [`SSLHonorCipherOrder on`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslhonorcipherorder)  directive.
4. That *should* result in the a connection with the strongest cipher the client supports. (in theory, your actual mileage may vary.)
5. If that cipher is below your threshold, then apply the logic to show your security message.
6. Secure the content that really needs a a strong cipher as [explained in the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#strongurl)

i.e. something along the lines of:

```
# be liberal in general
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLHonorCipherOrder on

<Location "/strong/area">
# but https://hostname/strong/area/ and below
# requires strong ciphers
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
</Location>
```